# What happens when I call a question the same name as a deleted one?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

What happens when someone gives a question the same name as a deleted one?

These are the possibilities that I have thought of:

1. The system will stop you
2. The URL of the new question will be modified, such as `question-name--2` instead of `question-name`
3. The question will be overwritten and inaccessible.

What would happen in this (hypothetical) case? I didn't try it myself because I didn't want to get suspended by site mods observing this behavior.

Comment: Questions are identified by numeric identifiers, not by their names. Thus, the system doesn't require that questions have unique names, and the URLs don't have to change, even when titles are edited. However, the system *does* tend to block questions that have identical titles as existing questions, but this is done for quality-control reasons, not technical ones. I do not recall whether deleted questions count for this purpose, but I do not think so. In other words, #2 and #3 are impossible. #1 might be true, but likely not if the other question is deleted.

Comment: However, none of that should be taken as encouragement or approval to delete and repost the same question. What is your actual problem? What are you trying to solve? Why do you need to know this information?

Comment: @CodyGray : I was curious on how this works.  I don't have any problem, I just wanted to know.  Thank you!

Comment: OK, cool! It's fine to ask how things work, of course. Being a moderator just makes me suspicious of people who might be trying to do things they shouldn't be doing. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray : I was guessing that was what you meant ;)